# Unable to get posted array from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post a group of arrays using the jQuery post method, but I am having trouble getting the value of the arrays. How can I get the values of the array that I have sent?
If somebody could help me i would be grateful....

Here is what i have done:

```
    $(document).ready( function()
        {
            $("#submit_info").click (
                function()
                {
                    var batchArr= new Array();
                    batchArr=arrPush('batch');
                    var facultyArr= new Array();
                    facultyArr=arrPush('faculty');
                    var levelArr= new Array();
                    levelArr=arrPush('level');
                    var sectionArr= new Array();
                    sectionArr=arrPush('section');
                    var shiftArr= new Array();
                    shiftArr=arrPush('shift');

                    $.post("server_side/college_info_insert.php",{
                            batchArr:batchArr,
                            facultyArr:facultyArr,
                            levelArr:levelArr,
                            sectionArr:sectionArr,
                            shiftArr:shiftArr
                        }, function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        });
                }
            );

            function arrPush(opt)
            {
                var Arr= new Array();
                Arr.push($("#"+opt+"_1").val());
                var count= $("#"+opt).val();
                var i=0;
                for(i;i<=count;i++)
                {
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        Arr.push($("#txt"+opt).val());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Arr.push($("#txt"+opt+i).val());
                    }
                }
                return Arr;
            }
        }
    );
```

How can I get the array values in the next page "college_info_insert.php" ??

Answer (score 1):

okay, so this is actually a really common issue.  It's unclear that you can't just send an array as-is from javascript to PHP and have it recognized.

The problem is that PHP doesn't know how to read in multiple values from a POST request - typically things like that require the PHP author to use brackets like: `varname[]`.

So, basically you must send variables as strings.  Using JSON you can send even complicated objects as strings to PHP using a single variable name.  Typically you'd use JSON.stringify or something along those lines - but if you have a simple array you might not even need it.

Here's a full example of the problem/solution, found using jquery and $.post:

Asume you have a file *myurl.php*:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And in a separate file (or the console), you try:

```
var myarray = Array('some','elements','etc');
var mydata = {postvar1: 'string', postvar2: myarray};
$.post('myurl.php', mydata, function(response) { 
    alert("response: " + response);
});
```

**This doesn't work!**  The result is that postvar2 only contains "etc".

The solution is force the array into a JSON string that can be decoded from PHP.

```
var myarray = Array('some','elements','etc');
var json_array = $.map(myarray,function(n) {
    return '"'+n+'"';
});
var mydata = {postvar1: 'string', postvar2: '['+json_array+']' };
$.post('myurl.php', mydata, function(response) { 
    alert("response: " + response);
});
```

ON the PHP side you now must use: `json_decode($_POST['myarray']);` to get your results in a proper array.

Note, this example assumes very simple strings or numbers in your array.  If you have complex objects, you will need to use a JSON.stringify function which will take care of extra quotes, escaping special characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood the question but wouldn't something like this work

```
if (isset($_POST['batchArr'])) {
   $batchArr = $_POST['batchArr'];
   // Then populate your html here e.g
   echo $batchArr[0];
```

}