# Trying to send an array from jquery to PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to load an array in my javascript. I need to send this array in some format to a PHP script that I'm going to call. In the example below, `gSelectedMeds` is my array. The value `count` will tell the PHP script how many `meds` items to expect to receive. I'm having trouble getting the data from the array into a format that I can send via the data option of $.ajax. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

The part of the code below that is giving me grief at the moment is the data option:

```
$('#export').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax-exportMeds.php',
        data: 
            {"number":gSelectedMeds.length},
            $.each(gSelectedMeds,
                function(intIndex, objValue){
                    {"med"+intIndex:objValue},
                }
            ),
        type: "GET",
        //dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            $('p#allMeds').text('');
            $('a.bank').text('');
            //clear array, bank and storedList divs
            $(this).text('');
            gSelectedMeds[] = '';
            //$('ul#storedList').fadeOut('fast');
            $('ul#storedList').text('');
            return false;
        },
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stringing out the array and sending a count at the end of the url that I called:

```
$('#export').click(function() {
        $.each(gSelectedMeds, 
         function(intIndex, objValue) {
            i=intIndex + 1;
            if(i>1) {string+='&';}
            string+='med'+i+'="'+objValue+'"';
         }
       )

       string += "&count="+i;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-exportMeds.php?'+string,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                  $('#dialog_layer').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,                                                 
                        bgiframe: true,
                        modal: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "OK": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                        }      
                  })
             }
        })
    });
```

Comment: @FilmJ suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838845/having-problem-getting-the-posted-array-from-jquery/1713985#1713985

Answer (score 4):

You should send the data as [json](http://json.org). Then you can read it using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) in php >= 5.2.0

Comment: do I need to create the JSON up front? how would I send it using the `data` option?

Comment: actually, I just used 'JSON.stringify' and that seems to have worked so far